# iOS Swift On Tab Leave Function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Is their a function I can call that gets triggered when the user clicks on a different tab?  For example: I use viewwillappear & viewdidload on the load, but what function can I use on the exit?

Comment: "clicks on a different tab" What is a "tab"?

Comment: I have a tabBar on the bottom of the page.  when a user clicks on a different tab I want to call a function before switching to the next page

Comment: Aha, thanks. So are you using a UITabBarController?

Comment: yeah im using UITabBarController

Comment: @Stop Tonio's, Do you want to do the action on the screen where from you are leaving by selecting other tab. Am I right?

Comment: Before going to the next page I need to make some changes on the current page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method `shouldSelectViewController`.

1. Set the UITabBarController's delegate to point to a class where you wish to implement the delegate methods.

3: Implement the method `shouldSelectViewController`:

```
extension MyClass: UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        if let myController = viewController as? MyClass {
            // do something
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: I put a break point in the function but when I switch tabs it never hits the break point

Comment: Did you subclass `UITabBarController` and set `self.delegate = self`?  You also don't have to subclass, you just have to set your UITabBarController's delegate to a class where you implement `shouldSelectViewController`.

Comment: I set UITabBarControllerDelegate next to my class name but the function still never gets called

Comment: I've changed my instructions to be more clear.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: This is wrong. You should never need to subclass UITabBarController, and certainly not merely in order to implement its delegate.

Comment: @matt You're absolutely right.  I did this in a project where I had to subclass UITabBarController (it was messy).  I've edited my answer to address your concerns. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

UITabBarController has a delegate (UITabBarControllerDelegate) which receives messages telling you what will happen (e.g. `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`) and what has happened (e.g. `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`).

Your view controller also gets `viewWillDisappear:`, but that does not distinguish this situation from any other (i.e. it could happen for other reasons).

Comment: what are the cons of using viewWillDisapper?

Comment: Only the fact that it "does not distinguish this situation from any other (i.e. it could happen for other reasons)". Gosh, I think I already said that. In other words, it doesn't actually answer the question you asked, which is how to respond to a tab change _in particular_.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers saying, define the `tabBarController` delegate method in your class which you have set as `delegate` to that tabBarController. This method will be called when you select a `tabItem`. This method is having parameter named `viewController` which is the one your are selecting. The `selectedViewController` property of the `tabBarController` has the previously selected view controller which you are leaving from (e.g.. the view controller which is going to disappear) .

in ObjC:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if [tabBarController.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]] {
        // do something you want to do on your viewcontroller, where you are leaving from.
        YourViewController *yourViewController = (YourViewController *)tabBarController.selectedViewController;
        [yourViewController doSomething];
    }

    return YES
}
```

In Swift:

```
 func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        if let yourViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? YourViewController {
            // do something you want to do on your viewcontroller, where you are leaving from.
            // yourViewController.doSomething()
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Problem is that my break point never gets hit inside the function.  I've set UiTabControllerDelegate  next to my class name.  Idk what else to do to get this function to execute